# How to select data based on certain duration of dates?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a dataset similar to the following. Across few dates, i.e., 2/16/2014 - 2/20/14, we have some categories. I want to select only those categories (with their corresponding dates) which span across these dates. For instance, based on this logic, C and D category should be excluded from this.

[image]

I am using this but clearly it does not help according to my problem.

```
df_1=df.loc['2014-02-16':'2014-02-20']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
no_days = pd.date_range(start='2/16/2014', end='2/20/2014').size
df.groupby('Category').filter(lambda x: len(x) == no_days)
```

Optimalized solution:

```
df[df.groupby('Category')['Category'].transform('size') == no_days]
```

Comment: You are welcome! I optimized the code a little.

Comment: Unfortunately `filter` here is really slow, so not optimalized solution

Comment: I meant by optimization this answer compared with the previous one. You will iterate only through the categories, then it is optimized if you have a big data!

Comment: Added to answer what I think

Comment: But that does not work, it returns an empty dataframe!